# AS3 Keyevent parent not selected

Tags: actionscript-3, input, actionscript, keyboard

I have a button on the first frame of a game im making, and when I click it it goes to the 2nd frame. You start the game as soon as it gets to the 2nd frame by pressing any button on the keyboard, but whenever it goes to the 2nd frame you have to click the screen before you can use the arrow keys. How can I make the keyboard input work without clicking the game

Here's some code from the first frame

```
    var buttoon1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new button1);
    var buttoon2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new button2);
    var buttoon3:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new button3);

    var button:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    button.addChild(buttoon1);
    button.x = 30;
    button.y = 50;
    button.width = 246;
    button.height = 43;
    addChild(button);

    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);

    function buttonClicked(e:Event) {
        gotoAndStop(2);
        removeChild(button);
    }
```

Here's some from the 2nd frame

```
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, down);

    function down(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (speed == 0) {
            speed = 10;
        }
    }
```

NOTE: I CLICK THE BUTTON IN THE GAME RIGHT BEFORE I TRY TO USE THE KEYBOARD (don't think I mean that keyboard input should work when another window is selected)

Comment: you could try manually setting the focus - though I don't think it will change anything:   `stage.focus = this`

Comment: Is this happening when you test in your IDE, or all the time regardless of context?  Your application shouldn't just loose focus when you click a button...

Comment: @LDMediaServices It happens no matter where I run it. I'll see if I can manually set it, but the problem isn't that the application loses focus, I guess it's just the stage losing focus

Comment: "stage.focus = this" worked perfectly, I think it might be that I had the button selected when it was removed so nothing was selected on the next frame, thanks!

Comment: That's a good theory, though oddly I've never run into this scenario before.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason nothing on the stage has the focus when it enters frame 2 (as per a comment perhaps the item that has the focus got removed from the display list)

You can remedy this by manually setting the focus to anything that is on the display list

```
stage.focus = this;
```